# CSS Media Query using multiple using the and logical operator not working as expected

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have added the following media query to my code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 800px){
    body {
        margin: 50px;
    }

    body, p {
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    #title {
        font-size: 4rem;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}
```

However, when displaying the page in a macBook 13, which has a screen bigger than the max-width of 800px, the styling is still following the media query above instead of the code outside of the media query.

Here's the link to the GitHub repo with the full HTML and CSS code:
[MVP survey-form repo](https://github.com/leinefran/free-code-camp/tree/master/survey-form)

It's a single page project.

Thanks.

Comment: what I don't understand is why you need a query between 700px and 800px. If you have a broken part in this range, this indicates that your html or css code is faulty. I suggest you review all your staff. I would also recommend using breakpoints located on bootstrap's own site for media query ranges. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

Comment: you have to learn about media queries, if the `max-width` is 800px **and** the `min-width` it means your code only will work/run in a screen that is wide as 700px an no wider than 800px, and a macbook 13 is way wider than 800px.

Comment: @dippas when you say that the code won't work for screens wider than 800px you mean only the code inside me media query or all the CSS code outside of the media query. After reading MDN's documentation on media query, my understanding was that for the screens bigger than 800px the CSS code outside of the media query would apply.

Comment: @LaneyFran sorry for not explaining well, I meant all the code inside that specific media query

Answer (score 0):

Media Queries are very sensitive to size changes and differences. So one possible solution is to type in media queries for all devices instead of just one. This allows you to make the program more responsive to size changes and makes the program not confuse the different sizes that the user may have.

I like to use this site for media queries to account for all screen resolutions and sizes:
https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/

Also, be sure to put `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your `<head>` tags to make it even more repsonsive.

Comment: This is a bad advice  `So one possible solution is to type in media queries for all devices instead of just one`.

Comment: @dippas Which is funny because the article provided in the answer warns against it.

Comment: @ZohirSalak do you believe in everything you read online? By the way this article is at least 4 years old, so yes I stand by my opinion

Comment: @dippas I think you misunderstood what i said

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the issue:

Besides the media query that I posted on the question, I also had this one right before it:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 300px){
    body {
        background-color: #605853;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    p, p.definition {
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    #title {
        font-size: 1.250em !important;
    }

    .form-control{
        height: 3rem;
    }

}
```

Now I know I should have included both. My bad.

When the page is bigger than 800px, instead of the page following the general CSS code, it was defaulting to the first media query because I have only specified min-width. A way to correct the problem is to add a max-width to that first media query. This took care of the problem:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 699px)
```

I'll read more on media queries, cause I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle small screens. It feels too broad.

Thank you for everyone who replied.

Comment: can I give you an advice?? don't use media queries with `min` and `max` at the same time because that will narrow it down so much, and will make you create a lot of media queries, let the content decide which breakpoints/media queries you need to use, either use mobile first approach (min-width only) or use non-mobile approach by using `max.width`